# Moving text on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I want to make the text move in opposite direction on mouse over.
The example of what I want to accomplish is [here](http://www.joeallison.co.uk/index.html).

I really wonder how to achieve this effect using CSS or JQuery.

Could anyone help me or give me a tip where I can find a tutorial how to do this?

Comment: Check this library out: http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

Comment: and this: [Animated banner with Parallax.js](http://www.andwecode.com/playground-demo/naruto-with-parallax-js/)

Comment: View the source code of the page. Voting to close as off-topic because you're both asking for a tutorial and don't have any specific code that you're having a problem fixing.

Comment: @ChipDean Thank You! The links are really helpful. I have already achieved what I wanted.